# WordPress Translation to french, at -> à not working

Tags: multi-language, localization, plugin-wpml, translation

I have a german / french blog. I installed the german WordPress version, so I already had de_DE.mo and de_DE.po in wp-content/languages.
After I realized that the content of a comment's `<time>`-element wasn't  translated, I googled and downloaded fr_FR.mo and fr_FR.po and put them in wp-content/languages. 
Now everything I tested works, except that 'at' doesn't get translated to 'à' ( I get: 3. février 2013 at 17:00).

So I opened fr_FR.po to see whether there is a translation available. I found this:

```
#. translators: 1: date, 2: time
#: wp-includes/comment-template.php:1367
msgid "%1$s at %2$s"
msgstr "%1$s à %2$s"
```

Which seems alright to me. So to make sure, I replaced the existing mo file with this. Still it does not work.

How do I make it translate 'at' to 'à'?

I'm using WPML.

Comment: How do you replaced the existing `mo` file? And why don't you use WPML's builtin string translation which is simpler than to dance with `gettext`?

Comment: Because those strings don't appear within WPML. They should, I guess? I replaced it by overwriting the old file.

Comment: I mean how do you created it. `gettext` or `poEdit`? And don't you make a muddle of `.po` and `.mo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what languages your site are in, when using WPML you should **never** install a localised WordPress version, instead you should just install the default one (i.e. US English).

Also make sure that you didn't change the LANG definition in your `wp-config.php` file, so that should read: `define ('WPLANG', '');`

Then you need to make sure that all the strings are in English (go to WPML->String Translation, scroll down to the bottom where you can set the language of the strings). After that rescan your theme for strings and you will be able to add translations for "at" in both German and French.